# how to get list of Object to JSon in webAPi

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net webAPi, I have created a LoanInfo class
which the values are set in a function and I finally put the LoanInfo in a list. I want to get all the values of the LoanInfo in Json but List always return empty values like [{},{}]. what am  I missing.
this is the loanInfo

```
public class LoanInfo
        {

             private String EmpID;
             private String amount;


            public LoanInfo(String EmpID,String amount)
            {


                this.EmpID = EmpID;
                this.amount = amount;

            }
```

this is the method

```
 public IEnumerable Get()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr);
            List<LoanInfo> loanInfo = new List<LoanInfo>();
            String query = "select EmpID,amount from employeeLoan";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    loanInfo.Add(new LoanInfo(read[0].ToString(), read[1].ToString()));
                }

                return loanInfo.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                String a = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you try to look at the inside of  `read`, does it returns something if you watch `read[0].ToString()`?

Comment: instead of `loanInfo.Add(new LoanInfo(read[0].ToString(), read[1].ToString()));` try `loanInfo.Add(new LoanInfo(read.getString(0), read.getString(1)));`

Comment: If your loanInfo variable is empty, it may be a problem with reading data from the database.
Tell us what you have in read variable, inside the while, like @CyrilGandon mentioned.

Comment: it is definitely getting values from the Database I can even seen the values when I use break Point in visual studio

Comment: you can also try using the names, like 'Convert.ToString(read["EmpID"])'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is you have private attributes, then when the serialization occurs, it can't read private values. Try to make properties on your `DTO` instead private fields.

```
public class LoanInfo
{    
     public string EmpID { get; set; }
     public string Amount { get; set; }

    public LoanInfo(string empID, String amount)
    {
        this.EmpID = EmpID;
        this.Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

I've refactored your code, try this:

```
public IEnumerable<LoanInfo> Get()
{
    List<LoanInfo> loanInfo = new List<LoanInfo>();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmpID, amount from employeeLoan", con);
            SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                loanInfo.Add(new LoanInfo(read[0].ToString(), read[1].ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }   
    }

    return loanInfo;
}
```